# oracle lag over dynamic column

Tags: sql, oracle, lag, dynamic-columns

in oracle SQL I want to sum current record column(col1) with col2 from previous record.

something like this:

```
col1         col2
-----        ----
  10          300
  12          312
  20          332
  50          382
```

I can use lag function for this query **WHEN** col2 is database column but
col2 calculated with a function. in otherwise col2 is dynamic column.

Now how to generate desired result?

Comment: Can you show us the query which generates the computed column?

Comment: SQL tables are unordered.  How are you defining "previous record"?

Answer (score 1):

`lag()` should work with function calls.  If you like, you can do this:

```
with t(col1, col2) as (
      select . . .
     )
select (col1 + coalesce(lag(col2) over (order by col1), 0) as thesum
from t;
```

Note:  this assumes that the ordering is specified by `col1`, which seems reasonable given the example in the question.

Comment: not work, I got error:
ORA-00938: not enough arguments for function